# Running fortify scan on .cs files

Tags: c#, .net, fortify

Is it possible to run Fortify scan on .cs files ?
have searched on net and SF but did not get any concrete answer.
The project structure is exactly like this https://pnppubsub.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Some of the projects are portable class libraries

Answer (score 3):

This is not really correct.  Fortify doe not NEED to compile the code so that it can perform the scan.  It can accept pre-compiled .Net Assemblies if they are build in a Debug configuration and the `.pdb` files are present.

For example a VS2012 project (typical VS folder structure):

```
MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.dll
MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.pdb
MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.csproj
MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.cs
MyProject\MyProject.sln
```

Your Translate step command would be something like:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyProjectScan -vsversion 11.0 MyProject
```

Sourceanalyzer will look at the MyProject folder and all subfolders for Assemblies and `.pdb` files.  The `-vsversion 11.0` parameter tells Sourceanalyzer what .Net framework the Assemblies were built with.

Answer (score 2):

No, Fortify requires a compile step to scan C# code. The easiest way to scan a .NET app with Fortify is to use the Visual Studio plugin or from the command prompt run:

sourceanalyzer -b mybuild devenv myproj.sln /REBUILD DEBUG

You can also try posting Fortify issues to their online forum at https://protect724.hp.com. The support group monitors those forums.

Updated:
I can't make a comment on James Nix's comment above because I don't have enough reputation, but what he says can work. The compile did occur (you have DLLs), so my answer is correct. I wanted to comment on a huge caveat that James doesn't address is making sure you have ALL of the code. When you scan .NET DLLs with PDB files, only the DLLs you point it to will be scanned. If it's a web app, the ASPX files need to be pre-compiled to produce DLLs with PDBs. If that doesn't occur the data flow analysis  will be significantly affected. In general I tell customers to only use this option only when you can't do the scan with the build. There's much room for error.